# How to get dynamic textbox value from div with dynamic id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I have an application where it has a list of records. I have to bind to div dynamically. I have to add a textbox for every record.

Now for every selected record, I have to get what the user entered the value in textbox also.

I want to get the selected person email address (whatever the user keyed in the textbox for that selected record)

```
<div class="row">
        <input type="checkbox"> <label>Bob</label> Email: <input type="textbox"/>  
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="checkbox"> <label>Bob</label> Email: <input type="textbox"/>  
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="checkbox"> <label>Bob</label> Email: <input type="textbox"/>  
    </div>

    <button onclick="saveSelectedEmail()">Submit</button>

<script>
function saveSelectedEmail(){

}
</script>
```

I want to get the selected person email address (whatever the user keyed in the textbox for that selected record)

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML so that we can see a running version of what you are dealing with. In general, working with IDs is not a good solution and dynamic IDs makes the solution even worse. There are many different ways to accomplish what you are trying to do that eliminate the need for IDs.

Comment: Side note; using a `result.Accounts.forEach` would allow you to remove all those `result.Accounts[i]` lines.

Comment: *cough* for is faster *cough*

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript or Jquery

> Javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Name: <input type="text" id="myText" value="Mickey">

<p>Click the button to change the value of the text field.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
console.log(document.getElementById("myText").value)
  document.getElementById("myText").value = "Johnny Bravo";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a dynamic id for every field or div.

> Html Code

```
<table id="userData" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Select</th>
            <th>Loan Id</th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Lender</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for emi in emis  %}
           <tr>
               <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkMe" name="checkBox" id="{{emi.userId._id.toString()}}"></td>
                <td>{{ emi._id.toString().slice(-6) }}</td>
                <td><a href="/admins/users/{{ emi.userId._id.toString() }}">{{ emi.userId.name }}</a></td>
                <td><a href="/admins/users/{{ emi.lenderId._id.toString() }}">{{ emi.lenderId.name }}</a></td>
           </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

> Javascript function

```
$('.checkMe').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    if (arr.includes(id)) {
        let index = arr.indexOf(id);
        arr.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
        arr.push(id);
    }
});
```